# Understanding Postgres work_mem, maintenance_work_mem and temp_buffers allocation

Tags: postgresql

I want to understand allocation of some postgresql.conf parameters. I want to know when maintenance_work_mem, work_mem and temp_buffers gets allocated.

As per my understanding,

1. maintenance_work_memory gets allocated at server start and this
   memory cannot be used by any other process.
2. work_mem gets allocated at time of query parsing, planner checks for number of sort methods
   or hash tables and allocates memory accordingly.  Sort operation may not use full allocated memory but still its reserved for that particular operation and cannot be used by any other process.
3. temp_buffers gets allocated at start of each session.

I have gone through the docs but didn't get any proper answer.

Is this understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

Maintenance work mem is allocated per session for VACUUM, CREATE INDEX and ADD FOREIGN KEYS, and it depends on parallel workers too like with autovacuum_max_workers = 3 and maintenance_work_mem = 1 GB then autovacuum will consume 1*3= 3GB of memory similarly while creating an index.

Now, work_mem also gets allocated per session depending on your sort/hash operations however I am sure Postgres don't reserve anything to be used in the future and for tuning this and you should always consider your number of parallel connection before allocating this memory as this parameter consumes memory work_mem*sort operations running in your cluster per connection.

Yes, that's true temp_buffers can be changed within individual sessions but only before the first use of temporary tables within the session.

http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2019/01/how-much-maintenanceworkmem-do-i-need.html by Robert Hass
https://www.depesz.com/2011/07/03/understanding-postgresql-conf-work_mem/  by Deprez
https://www.interdb.jp/pg/pgsql02.html and https://severalnines.com/database-blog/architecture-and-tuning-memory-postgresql-databases was very helpful understanding the memory architecture

Answer (score 1):

- `work_mem` is the maximum memory that a single step in an execution plan can use. It is allocated by the executor freed when the query execution is done.
- `maintenance_work_mem` is the same, but for maintenance operations like `CREATE INDEX` and `VACUUM`.
- `temp_buffers` is used to cache temporary tables and remains in use for the duration of the database session.